# OPE of Energy-Momentum Tensor in Polchinski

Tags: coordinate-systems, string-theory, conformal-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I am learning Polchinski's textbook on string theory. In section 2.6 I get confused when Polchinski introduce two natural choices of complex coordinates of closed strings

$$w=\sigma^1+i\sigma^2,\tag{2.6.3}$$

$$z=\mathrm{exp}(-iw)=\mathrm{exp}(-i\sigma^1+\sigma^2).\tag{2.6.4}$$

In 2.2.11 we derived the OPE of $TT$ in what now called w coordinate which looks like:

$$T(w)T(0)\sim\frac{c}{2w^4}+\frac{2}{w^2}T(0)+\frac{1}{w}\partial T(0).$$

but in formula 2.6.18 where we are using $z$ coordinate to derive the Virasoro algebra using the same OPE:

$$T(z)T(0)\sim\frac{c}{2z^4}+\frac{2}{z^2}T(0)+\frac{1}{z}\partial T(0).$$

This is where I get confused, is this true in this two coordinate system? If it is true it looks nontrivial to me since we know $$T_{ww}=(\partial_wz)^2T_{zz}+\frac{c}{24}\tag{2.6.9}$$ which is 2.6.9 in Polchinski, why polchhinski did not give a argument for this? Or did I misunderstand something in the textbook? any hint would be useful.

Comment: In the Polchinski equations you quote, $w$ is a co-ordinate on the cylinder and $z$ is a co-ordinate on the plane. Below when you write $T(w)T(0)$ and $T(z)T(0)$, $w$ and $z$ are both co-ordinates on the plane.

Comment: @Connor Behan Thanks for your comment, but sorry that I can't see why you say that $T(w)T(0)$ and $T(z)T(0)$ are both co-ordinates on the plane, on the contrary, I think they should be co-ordinates on the cylinder because the OPE of TT are derived using w co-ordinates which is on the cylinder, for example, it is in the w co-ordinates that we can write $S\sim\int\mathrm{d}^2w\partial X^\mu\bar{\partial}X_\mu$ from which we derive the OPE, am I wrong? Can you be more specific? thank you very much!

Comment: Try writing the action of the free boson on the plane then. The $T(z) T(0)$ OPE you wrote is invariant upon taking $z$ to itself times $e^{2\pi i}$. Not itself plus $2\pi i$.